# How to scrape faster using Selenium and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

Thanks to the help of the beautiful people here on SO I was able to put together some code to scrape a web page. Due to the page's dynamic nature, I had to use Selenium as BeautifulSoup can only be used alone when you have to scrape static pages.

One drawback is that the whole process of opening a page, waiting until a pop-up gets opened and input introduced is taking a huge amount of time. And time is a problem here, as I have to scrape around 1000 pages (1 page per zipcode), which takes around 10 hours.

How can I optimize the code so that this operation will not take for so long?

I will leave the full code and list of zipcodes below for reproduction.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

time_of_day=[]
price=[]
Hours=[]
day=[]
disabled=[]
location=[]

danishzip = pd.read_excel (r'D:\Danish_ZIPs.xlsx')

for i in range(len(danishzip)):
    try:
        zipcode = danishzip['Zip'][i]

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\lib\chromedriver_77.0.3865.40.exe')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://www.nemlig.com/")

        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".timeslot-prompt.initial-animation-done")))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='tel'][class^='pro']"))).send_keys(str(zipcode))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.prompt__button"))).click()

        time.sleep(3)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')


        for morn,d in zip(soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'),soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__item')):
            location.append(soup.find('span', class_='zipAndCity').text)
            time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
            Hours.append(morn.text)
            price.append(morn.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
            day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)
            if 'disabled' in d['class']:
                disabled.append('1')
            else:
                disabled.append('0')

        for after,d in zip(soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'),soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__item')):
            location.append(soup.find('span', class_='zipAndCity').text)
            time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
            Hours.append(after.text)
            price.append(after.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
            day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)
            if 'disabled' in d['class']:
                disabled.append('1')
            else:
                disabled.append('0')

        for evenin,d in zip(soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'),soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__item')):
            location.append(soup.find('span', class_='zipAndCity').text)
            time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
            Hours.append(evenin.text)
            price.append(evenin.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
            day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)
            if 'disabled' in d['class']:
                disabled.append('1')
            else:
                disabled.append('0')

        df = pd.DataFrame({"time_of_day":time_of_day,"Hours":Hours,"price":price,"Day":day,"Disabled" : disabled, "Location": location})
        print(df)
        driver.close()
    except Exception:
        time_of_day.append('No Zipcode')
        location.append('No Zipcode')
        Hours.append('No Zipcode')
        price.append('No Zipcode')
        day.append('No Zipcode')
        disabled.append('No Zipcode')
        df = pd.DataFrame({"time_of_day":time_of_day,"Hours":Hours,"price":price,"Day":day,"Disabled" : disabled, "Location": location})
        driver.close()
```

zipcodes list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_Denmark

Comment: @ Questieme Will something like this (the json url) help? https://www.nemlig.com/webapi/4CbKt3-4-YDwVV4BQ/2019101414-60-240/1/0/Menu/main?navigationDepth=15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a simple request to get all information in json format:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'dnt': '1',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'authority': 'www.nemlig.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.nemlig.com/',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.nemlig.com/webapi/v2/Delivery/GetDeliveryDays?days=8', headers=headers)

json_data = response.json()
```

You can change `days=` parameter to 20 for example and get 20 days data.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this way! Thank you very much!

Comment: An addition to this - I wanted to ask if there is any way I could get this information based on the Zipcodes. Sometimes the values differ from zipcode to zipcode so it would be helpful to have a field where I can see it.

Comment: An update to my latest comment - as I can see it right now, after using your code I would have an empty field `PostalDistrictCode` field in json_data. I looked through the dev tools on the page and the only thing I could find is AddPostCode method, but no GET method like `GetDeliveryDays` but with a parameter for the zipcode. I don't really understand where do they get the zipcode from, though.

Comment: They have anti-scraping bot and will block your IP.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is not for web scraping.

Try to find *internal api* of nemlig.com.
Instead of wait for JS processed, find http endpoints that returns data which you want. You can do it with developer tools in your browser or with some tools like Burp Suite.

After that just harvest it with requests/urllib.

https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/web-scraping-discovering-hidden-apis/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will look into that!